# How to scroll back in screen within a ssh session from OS X?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, terminal, gnu-screen

I do the following:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Open a ssh session to a remote Linux server
3. Open a screen session on the server
4. Start a program who breaks with many lines of error reporting…

How can I scroll up to read that?

And no, fixing the program is *not* a solution for now…

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think linux TTYs hold any history, themselves. When you're on a console TTY, you can page back up by using `Ctrl`+`PgUp`, but I doubt that will work in your case. 

Terminal.app must be configurable to hold more than its default amount of history, though. (or is it too late for that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i got it:

```
Ctrl + A, ESC
```

and then vim-like commands:

```
Ctrl + u or Ctrl + d
```

Answer (score 14):

You can modify `.screenrc` to allow mouse-based scrollback:

http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/mac-os-x-terminal-and-gnu-screen-scrollback/

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

If you did a `man screen` you can see the options available.

When in screen you can do the following:
`CTRL+A` (release), `[`

You can then use the arrows to scroll around the window. To get out of scrolling you can do a `CTRL+C`.

Comment: +1 for that. Ignore my comment, I somehow managed to blank the part that mentioned screen...

Comment: @SmallClanger: Not only that, but the OP mentioned OS X, not Linux. Besides, on Linux, gnome-terminal and xterm, among others, have scroll-back buffers. Try shift-pageup.

Answer (score 6):

Nathan's got it right, though I've always been a fan of `Ctrl+A` + `ESC`.  `ESC` is yet another way to get out of copy mode.

It is worth considering, however, that scrollback history has a size limit and if you really want to play it safe, it's generally better to either redirect output to a file (or pipe it to tee if you want screen output as well).

Comment: The scrollback is adjustable, though, using the *defscrollback* option in .screenrc. I typically keep mine set to 5000 lines, but sometimes I bump it up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Besides using the scroll-back buffer in `screen`, Terminal.app may respond to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Up</kbd> (perhaps <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd> on a MacBook).

Another option would be something like:

```
your_prog 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: Apparently in Terminal.app plain PgUp and PgDn will access the scrollback buffer, whereas Shift+PgUp and Shift+PgDn have to be used to send those keys to the application instead: http://www.rickycampbell.com/fix-osx-terminal-pgup-pgdn-home-and-end

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when scrolling the mouse ...